# Regex for considering same type of group as one match not two

Tags: python, regex

I have an HTML document that considers a regex match.The regex for the group is `(ITEM\s*\W+\s*([1-9])\b\s*\W+\s*(?P<title>\w.*?))(?=\s*$)`.Now this regex is matching the groups in the text given below correctly.

```
Item 5 || Some english text||64
Item 5(c) ||Some english text|| 89     #multiline,unicode,insensitive flag is set
Item 8|| Some english text ||78
```

Now I want the regex to consider Item 5 and do not consider 5(c).

Comment: Please check the regex you have posted. It misses one left parenthesis. Edit it.

Comment: I have edited the regex.Thanks for considering.

Comment: When 5(c) is not considered, do you still want the rest of that line to be captured?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `(?!\(.\))` between ([1-9]) and \b